# Sum of imports of a line passing two point...

Tags: geometry

let's say a person has to give me 45000€ in total, paying once each trimester, in progression. We agreed starting from 9000€ the first trimester and 14000€ the last trimester.
Of course you can do it by hand, but since I'm studying geometry I wanted to calculate the formula of a line passing 2 points with `A(3,9)` and `B(12,14)` and the formula is `y = ((5/9)x)+66/9`. It works but the final sum is 46000€ and not 45000€?? Why do I get this extra 1000€? Is my geometric approac wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: There is no four term *arithmetic progression* with first term $9000$ and fourth term $14000$ that adds up to $45000$.

Answer (score 0):

First, isn't trimester thrice a year? What you wrote suggests you're paid to four times a year.

Second, it doesn't work since the amounts you agreed upon aren't right. You can fix this by multiplying the payments by 45/46.

Third, if you want to be paid thrice a year, you can take the middle payment to be 15 000 and the other two 15 000 -x and 15000 +x.

Fourth, you want to have interest on the loan too. That's why you get the extra 1000€.

Comment: FIY: Trimester: A period of three months (Latin tri +mensis=month or moon) In Europe, where financial years start on Jan 1 each year, often Jan+Feb+Mar etc.

Thank for the other points clarifications!